# Javascript grid for huge data representation

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid

I need a javascript grid for representing huge data( i mean thousands of records ) with a pretty fast searching and sorting feature. I've found a few, but i dont really know which would be the best. I would need some basic features built in the grid such as: -sorting, searching in rows, filtering etc. 
Anyone know a grid which would suit my needs?

Comment: An array or a database?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. Array or json objec or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try using this(JSLightGrid): https://github.com/chanakyachatterjee/JSLightGrid. It's pure javascript(no need of jquery or any other library), responsive and quite fast when comes to huge data. eg sorts 2k records in 52 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com)? It does all the things that you are looking to do. It was written for financial applications, so is very capable with the 'lots of data' requirement.